# Why isn't the A4 sized paper preferred over the letter size in the US?

Tags: size

The first question I had was whether either of the sizes had any objective benefits. A quick Google search for the string `A4 vs letter` revealed a few answers. The most relevant answer I found is on the following link:
http://betweenborders.com/wordsmithing/a4-vs-us-letter/

The width to length ratio of the A4 allows it to be folded into half without altering the ratio. Apparently this is quite important. Yet the US (and a few other countries) are hanging on to the letter size.

In my personal opinion the letter size is more elegant as compared to the A4 size. After having used the A4 size for most of my life, the change to the letter size makes it seem to me to be easy to hold and a bit more easier on the eyes. The A4 is tad bit too long. That's a subjective judgement. I am looking for the objective benefits, if there are any, for using the letter size (apart from the legacy benefits of course).

Answer (score 4):

It's for the similar reasons the US still uses inches and feet instead of meters. The US has so much inertia invested in letter page size, switching to something very slightly different has a very poor cost benefit tradeoff. Additionally, being defined in a metric scale, it would be obnoxious to deal with on an imperial basis.

So, no, there are no other objective benefits.

Comment: Many countries had much invested in imperial units, but most of the world has switched to metric with no ill-effect. There are plenty of benefits to using the metric system over the imperial one -- if not only to be able to communicate with the rest of the world in sensible units. There's nothing more frustrating than viewing a recipe online with everything being measured in 'cups', or working out whether a gallon is a British-gallon or a US-gallon.